# netbeans blank line after if statement

Tags: if-statement, netbeans, code-formatting

In netbeans how can one format it so that after if-blocks there is a blank line? I have been searching through the formatting options and trying different things to no avail.

e.g.

```
if ($lifegivesyoulemons) {
   echo "say f' it and bail";
}

if ($if_they_take_my_stapler) {
   echo "i will set the building on fire";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically for `if-else` loop this should work for all methods also.

In your Netbeans IDE goto **Tools** - then select **Editor** tab.

Under **Editor** tab select **Formatting** select language PHP (as per your `if-else` loop in question) and Category **Blank Lines**

[image: Netbeans screen-shot 1]

And then scroll down in **After Function** field change value 0 to 1 like this

[image: Netbeans screen-shot 2]

Click on **Apply** and **Ok**

Now select **On Save** tab. Select language PHP

[image: Netbeans screen-shot 3]

Uncheck **Use all language settings**. After that from drop down select **All Lines**. Click on **Ok**

Now you type code hit Ctrl + S Netbeans automatically formats your code with one blank line after `}` brace (bracket). (As of I know this should work both methods and loops also).